# Linked list with structures using command line arguments

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments, singly-linked-list

I have written the C code to store and use employee data using a linked list.

The logic works perfectly. I get the correct output when I pass the inputs using function calls (commented part). But I want to try the same using command-line arguments. I don't know how to do that and I get the segmentation fault. Could somebody help me learn how to do it or point out if there's any mistake in the 'main()' function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct employee
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
}info;

struct node
{
    info data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* head;

void insert(char name[20], int age)
{
    struct node* temp= NULL;
    temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(temp->data.name,name);
    temp->data.age=age;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
        return;
    }

    struct node* temp1 = head;

    if((temp->data.age) <= (temp1->data.age))
    {
        temp->next=temp1;
        head=temp;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while( (temp->data.age)>(temp1->data.age) && (temp1->next != NULL) )
        {
            if((temp->data.age) < (temp1->next->data.age))
            {
                break;
            }
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        temp->next = temp1->next;
        temp1->next = temp;
    }
}

void print(int n)
{
    if((head==NULL)||(n<1))
        return;

    struct node* temp = head;

    if(n==1)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", temp->data.name, temp->data.age);
        return;
    }

    for(int i=1; i<=n-1; i++)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        if(temp==NULL)
        {
            printf("Specified number exceeds linked list limit\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("%s %d\n", temp->data.name, temp->data.age);
}

void remove_(int n)
{
    if((head==NULL)||(n<1))
        return;

    struct node* temp = head;

    if(n==1)
    {
        head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }

    for(int i=1; i<=n-2; i++)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        if((temp->next)==NULL)
            return;
    }

    struct node* temp1=NULL;
    temp1 = temp->next;
    temp->next = temp1->next;
    free(temp1);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    head= NULL;

    if(!(strcmp(argv[1],"insert")))
    {
        int age=atoi(argv[3]);                  // ./main insert sunil 40
        insert(argv[2], age);  
    }


    if(!(strcmp(argv[1],"print")))              // ,.main print 2
    {
        int n=atoi(argv[2]);
        print(n);
    }


//  insert("williamson",40);
//  insert("micheal",30);
//  print(5);
//  print(2);
//  print(1);
//  insert("John",24);
//  remove_(3);
//  print(3);
//  print(1);
//  print(2);

 return 0;
}
```

I get Segmentation fault or sometimes no result

Comment: The code seems to run fine with no segfaults? Could you include a stacktrace using something like GDB?

Comment: @gunsofboom Does the segmentation fault occurs when the commented lines are uncommented?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The program works fine without any faults when the commented lines are uncommented. Just dont know how to pass the inputs using command-line-arguments method

Comment: @gunsofboom As I pointed out in my answer the function insert is invalid and has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if there are enough arguments before accessing them. For example, if you want to "insert"

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    head= NULL;
    if(argc > 3)
        if(!(strcmp(argv[1],"insert")))
        {
            int age=atoi(argv[3]);                  // ./main insert sunil 40
            insert(argv[2], age);  
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this :)
But may i know how to pass the arguments for this program

Comment: If you named your executable as "my_code", then you have to execute it as: 

./my_code insert williamson 40

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the segmentation fault occurs when the commented lines are uncommented.

The problem is that the function `insert` is defined incorrectly and has undefined behavior.

Within this loop

```
    while((temp->data.age) > (temp1->data.age))
    {
        if((temp->data.age) < (temp1->next->data.age))
        {
            break;
        }
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
```

you do not check whether `temp1` is equal to `NULL`.

Also you should check whether the number of supplied arguments for the function main is valid.

Comment: Hi, I have a check whether 'head' is null or not. If head is not null only then head is assigned to temp1, or else it returns

Comment: @gunsofboom Within the loop you perform temp1 = temp1->next; temp1->next can be equal to NULL, So and temp1 will be equal to NULL.

Comment: oh yes, thanks for identifying :) I will rectify it

Comment: Edited the previous while to "while( (temp->data.age)>(temp1->data.age) && (temp1->next != NULL) )"